# UWP Visual C# WebView InvokeScript to change CSS throws Exception

Tags: c#, css, webview, uwp, invokescript

I am trying to change the CSS of a loaded Website in a WebView (not local) by injecting a Javascript Function. I found these two Articles ([Article 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25422035/how-to-append-new-javascript-to-current-html-webbrowser-control), [Article 2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6defab0e-60b9-4b7a-a59c-e761fad664ca/how-to-apply-css-or-formatting-to-rss-dynamic-html-?forum=winappswithcsharp)) but after implementing both Versions I always get the following Exception:
**System.NotImplementedException {"The method or operation is not implemented."}**

This is my Code so far:

MainPage.xml

```
...
  <WebView x:Name="WebView" LoadCompleted="webViewCSS_LoadCompleted"/>
...
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
...
private void webViewCSS_LoadCompleted (object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
  {
     addCss();
  }

private void addCss()
  {
     try
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("function setCSS() { ");
            sb.Append("document.getElementsByClassName('app')[0].style.width = '100%';");
            sb.Append("} ");

            string script = sb.ToString();
            WebView.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { script });
            WebView.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { "setCSS()" });
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
...
```

I dont know why it is throwing an Exception. I hope the Information that I have given is enough. If not please get back to me :-)

Thank you in advance for your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WebView.InvokeScript method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescript.aspx) may be unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1. Instead, we need to use [WebView.InvokeScriptAsync method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescriptasync.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

You can refer to [WebView class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview), there are examples in the Remarks part of the official document:

> you can use `InvokeScriptAsync` with the JavaScript `eval` function to inject the content into the web page.